# Xero - How to reconcile a transaction when the period has been locked

Tags: software, bookkeeping, reconciling

I use Xero for my consultancy company's book-keeping. My accounts from a couple of months ago are locked (due to submitting a VAT (UK sales tax) return). I have an unreconciled bank transaction within that period. If I try to reconcile it, Xero says:

> Error: Your accounts are locked by your adviser up until 31 May 2018. Your action must occur after this date.

Does anyone know how to deal with this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've just had the same problem.

tl;dr - It seems you have to unlock the transaction period to reconcile.  The danger here is that may affect reports you have already made, so you should probably talk to your [advisor/accountant/person who set the lock date]

Long version:
The Xero help pages identify a similar situation [here](https://central.xero.com/s/article/Can-t-allocate-a-supplier-credit-note#Creditnoteisinalockedperiod)  where lock dates affect allocating credits to invoices outside of the lock period.

For us, we had had a bank feed transaction dated 30th June and a supplier invoice dated 1st July.  In future, I'm going to make sure we've reconciled everything before we need to lock dates for year end.

To [reconcile](https://go.xero.com/Setup/FinancialSettings.aspx), I had to visit General Settings > Financial Settings, at the [bottom of the page are two types of lock date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4LTt.jpg). I set these to a date before my unreconciled transaction (28th June), reconcile, then set them back.

Comment: Update: Whilst for us this didn't affect our published accounts it easily could have, so be careful and check with the person who needed to set a date lock. 

For us The effect was to INCREASE the balance of account 789 (a bank account/credit card) and REDUCE the balance of account 800 (creditors control).  However, since they were both CREDITORS there was no effect on the published accounts.